# Procedure for obtaining the formulas of the half angle

Tags: amsmath, arrays

I am trying to write the procedure for obtaining the formulas of the half angle, but nothing at all. I don't know if it is too complicated to do it.

[image]

My current code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) - \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) &=\cos \alpha \\
    \cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) +\sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) &=1\\
    \\
    2\cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) &= 1+\cos \alpha \Rightarrow \cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) =\dfrac{1+\cos \alpha}{2}\Rightarrow \cos \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos \alpha}{2}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which aspect are you stuck on, what does your current code or work look like? That image is not difficult to produce but it is best if you can demonstrate that you have tried and got stuck on some aspect or other please `:)`

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `alignat`, which is similar to `align` but with no spacing between the columns. (Also, you have to specify how many column-pairs.) Then you can add a `rule` inside `\rlap` for the horizontal line.

The columns alternate right-left alignment, so to get consecutive left-aligned columns, use `&&`. In your expression, the `\cos` is left-aligned, then the `=` is left aligned again.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) - \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)&&=\cos \alpha \\
    &\cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) +\sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)&&=1\\[-1ex]
    &\rlap{\rule{5.1cm}{.5pt}}\\[-1ex]
   2&\cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)&&= 1+\cos \alpha \Rightarrow \cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) =\dfrac{1+\cos \alpha}{2}\Rightarrow \cos \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos \alpha}{2}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: Yes. Yes I did.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\halpha}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}
\begin{array}{
  >{\displaystyle}l
  >{\displaystyle{}}l
  >{\displaystyle{}}l
}
\cos^2 \halpha - \sin^2 \halpha &= \cos \alpha \\
\addlinespace
\cos^2 \halpha + \sin^2 \halpha &= 1 \\
\addlinespace
\cmidrule{1-2}
2\cos^2 \halpha                 &= 1+\cos \alpha
&  \implies \cos^2 \halpha = \frac{1+\cos \alpha}{2} \\
\addlinespace
&& \implies \left|\cos \halpha\right| = \sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos \alpha}{2}}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Defining the local command `\halpha` is useful for keeping the code as tight as possible. But if you modify the definition into

```
\newcommand{\halpha}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}
```

you get the less distracting (in my opinion)

[image]

**Mathematical note.** I find that using ± in this context is misleading: students find it after having learned to use ± in the context of quadratic equations, where it has a *very different* meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an altogether different layout to consider. It avoids the appearance of a long "tail" wandering off aimlessly to the right in row 3. In addition, it uses `\tfrac` rather than `\dfrac`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathrlap macro
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \midrule macro
\newcommand\alphahalf{\bigl( \tfrac{\alpha}{2} \bigr)}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
\cos^2 \alphahalf - \sin^2 \alphahalf &=\cos \alpha \\
\cos^2 \alphahalf + \sin^2 \alphahalf &=1 \\
\midrule
2\cos^2 \alphahalf &= 1+\cos \alpha \\[2\jot]
\Rightarrow \cos^2 \alphahalf &= \mathrlap{(1+\cos \alpha)/2} \\
\Rightarrow \cos \alphahalf   &= \mathrlap{\pm \sqrt{(1+\cos \alpha)/2}}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```