# Obtain the formula of the half angle - Question

Tags: align, amsmath

I have a question regarding the answer of @Sandy G of the following one: [Procedure for obtaining the formulas of the half angle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675814/procedure-for-obtaining-the-formulas-of-the-half-angle)

I'm trying to do the same but for other formula:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    -\cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) &+\sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) &&=-\cos \alpha \\
    \cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) &+\sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) &&=1\\[-1ex]
    &\rlap{\rule{5.1cm}{.5pt}} \\[-1ex]
    2&\sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)&&= 1-\cos \alpha \Rightarrow \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1-\cos \alpha}{2}\Rightarrow \sin \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos \alpha}{2}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

But the line is offset to the left and the $2\sin^2$ if it could be glued to the equal symbol....

Comment: Look closer to your `&` placements. And please edit your question to give a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: @SebGlav, I tried to play with the positions of the &, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pad it with some hspace for a quick and dirty fix:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    -&\cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) + \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)&&=-\cos \alpha \\
    &\cos^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) +\sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)&&=1\\[-1ex]
    &\rlap{\rule{5.1cm}{.5pt}}\\[-1ex]
    &\hspace{4.7em}2\sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)&&= 1-\cos \alpha \Rightarrow \sin^2 \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1-\cos \alpha}{2}\Rightarrow \sin \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos \alpha}{2}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: sin half angle derivation]